# Spring boot log4j pattern

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

I'm moving from logback to log4j and I have to replicate the default configuration in Spring Boot for Log4j.

That's what I have so far, but it doesn't look like the previous one.

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
2014-03-05 10:57:51.112  INFO 45469 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2014-03-05 10:57:51.253  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-03-05 10:57:51.253  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1358 ms
2014-03-05 10:57:51.698  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-03-05 10:57:51.702  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
```

Where is the config file so I can check the pattern and the rest of the config and see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

This is the pattern you are looking for:

```
"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}  %-4p %4L --- [%15.15t] %-40.40C : %m%n%wEx"
```

You will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this pattern! I needed to change it a little bit to get class names in the expected format:

`%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-4p %4L --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%wEx`

Answer (score 2):

### [Spring Boot Default Logback Configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java)

```
private static final String CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN = "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} "
            + "%clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} "
            + "%clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} "
            + "%clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}";
```

Comment: Can you give a hint how to color log levels only. For instance: error is red, info is white, etc.?

Comment: The link is expired (404)

Comment: @valijon Updated with permalink

Answer (score 0):

You may find guide which gives detailed explanation about PatternLayout from [org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

There is a sample, maybe you could get some inspiration.

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS}{UTC} [%t] %c{1} -|%-5X{requestId}|- %m%n" />
</layout>
```

Application log likes:

> INFO  2016-07-21/12:14:49.613 [http-nio-9040-exec-9] QrCodeTestController -|29909|- BufferedImage is BufferedImage@2e5adf04: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@4996a909 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 556 height = 776 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 6782